# Create File in Ubuntu Using C

Tags: c, file

Create file using C in Ubuntu.
I've tried that code and it doesn't work.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h>
int main() 
{ 
  char a[50];
  char command[150];
  printf("Enter The File's Name");
  gets(a);
  strcpy("touch ");
  strcat("a");
  system(command);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please turn on warnings on your compiler and read them. The code you gave shouldn't compile at all.

Comment: You forgot to pass `command` to `strcpy` and `strcat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strcpy should be `strcpy(command, "touch")` and your strcat should be `strcat(command, a)`

But there are much better ways to create an empty file...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. 
What's the best way then?

Comment: There are several.  There is no "best" way, but one way would be FILE *f = fopen("filename", "w");  (and make sure you close the file when you're done with it).   I recommend you get yourself a good book on C programming to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to pass `command` to `strcpy` and `strcat`.
2. You are using the string `"a"` in the call to `strcat` instead of the variable `a`.

Replace

```
  strcpy("touch ");
  strcat("a");
```

by

```
  strcpy(command, "touch ");
  strcat(command, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were trying to do the code in this way, though as Jeff told you it is not the best way to create a file-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char a[50],command[150];
   printf("Enter the file name: ");
   gets(a);
   sprintf(command,"touch %s",a);
   system(command);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
What's the best way to create a file then?

Comment: For me it is the using of FILE pointer...I always use file pointer, because commands may vary in platforms as touch will not work in windows